# How do you accept any URL in a Python Bottle server?

Tags: python, bottle

Using a Bottle Sehttp://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#wildcard-filters

I'd like to accept any url, and then do something with the url.

e.g.

```
@bottle.route("/<url:path>")
def index(url):
  return "Your url is " + url
```

This is tricky because URLs have slashes in them, and Bottle splits by slashes.

Comment: Something I've tried: @bottle.route("/hello") runs just fine, but @bottle.route("/hello/<url:path>") doesn't work...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on new Bottle (v0.10), use a re filter:

```
@bottle.route("/<url:re:.+>")
```

You can do that with old parameters too:

```
@bottle.route("/:url#.+#")
```

Comment: Hmm, I was trying <url:re:.+> and it gave me a 404 not found.  However, I tried your old parameters solution at it works!  So this means I have an old version of Bottle installed?  I have Bottle installed here /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/bottle.py and it says it is version 0.9.7, so why would this be?

Comment: Bottle 0.10 was released just a week ago. Bottle 0.9 is not really old, but don't have filters like I showed with "/<url:re:.+>". Take a look at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/changelog.html#release-0-10 to know new things you can have updating to new version.

Comment: This would work in some cases, but it will choke on urls containing #$ and similar...

Comment: @starenka this is a 2 year old answer. The right way to do it is the first one, so you will not have this issue: `@bottle.route("/<url:re:.+>")`

Comment: @iurisilvio yes, that's the one i'm speaking about, try it for yourself if you don't trust me ;)

Comment: @starenka if you want to call a url with `#`, this character should be escaped or it will not even hit the server. `http://localhost:8080/x/#test` will call `/x/`. `http://localhost:8080/x/%23test` will call `/x/#test`. It is not bottle related.

Answer (score 9):

I think you (OP) were on the right track to begin with.  `<mypath:path>` should do the trick.

I just tried it out with bottle 0.10 and it works:

```sh
~>python test.py >& /dev/null &
[1] 37316
~>wget -qO- 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/hello/cruel/world'
Your path is: /hello/cruel/world
```

Here's my code.  What happens when you run this on your system?

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('<mypath:path>')
def test(mypath):
    return 'Your path is: %s\n' % mypath

run(host='localhost', port=8090)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In Bottle 0.12.9 i did this to achieve optional dynamic routes:

```
@bottle.route("/<url:re:.*>")
def index(url):
  return "Your url is " + url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bottle.route("/hello/:myurl")
def something(myurl):
    print myurl
    return "Your url was %s" % myurl
```

Should work just fine

I would then write the regex into the function itself.

Or you could do it with a new filter, but to do that you have to write a filter function and add it to the app.

Comment: I need it to accept URLs though, and URLs have slashes in them.  For instance: "localhost:8080/hello/http://www.test.com/some/page" needs to match the URL completely.

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with Bottle, but what is the value of myurl in that case? If it's just "test.com", I assume the rest of the url pieces are being passed in as well. Try def something(*args) and see if all of the pieces are in args.