# Passing arguments containing slashes to bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I need to pass strings containing slashes through the last argument in a url to my bottlepy server but since slashes get treated like argument separators the server doesn't handle it the way I need to. 
I found a page about how flask supports this:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/
But haven't found a similar solution in bottle yet

Comment: Found it:

@route('/group/<items:re:.+>')

from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171618/how-do-you-accept-any-url-in-a-python-bottle-server

Comment: With Bottle 0.11 you should prefer `path` over `re`... but whatever floats your boat.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want [`:path`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#dynamic-routes):

> :path matches all characters including the slash character in a
>   non-greedy way and may be used to match more than one path segment.

For example,

```
@route('/root/<path:thepath>')
def callback(thepath):
    # `thepath` is everything after "/root/" in the URI.
    ...
```

---

EDIT: In response to OP's comment (below), here's a snippet which works for me:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/add/<uid>/<collection>/<group>/<items:path>')
def add(uid, collection, group, items):
    return 'your uri path args: {}, {}, {}, {}\n'.format(uid, collection, group, items)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081)
```

Yields:

```
% ~>curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/add/1/2/3/and/now/a/path'
your uri path args: 1, 2, 3, and/now/a/path
```

Comment: Well, that's the Flask solution that was described in the link I gave but in bottle it gives me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 105, in <module>
 ...
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bottle-0.11.6-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 328, in add
    mask, in_filter, out_filter = self.filters[mode](conf)
KeyError: 'items'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Okay.  I need to see your code to help you further.  How are you defining the route?

Comment: `@route('/add/<uid>/<collection>/<group>/<items:re:.+>')
    def add(uid, collection, group, items):`

Comment: that's not supposed to be one line stackoverflow seems to be deleting the whitespace

Comment: Thanks.  Really need to see more of your code to help you, but I took the two lines you pasted above and tried them, and they work fine for me.  Bottle 0.11.6.  I'll edit my answer to include the code I used.  In any case it sounds like you found a workaround, so you're all set.  Cheers.