# bottlepy route match any url with exceptions

Tags: python, regex, bottle

I'm writing a template on bottle for every request. So localhost and locahost/mypage and localhost/mypage/about will call the same template. I checked here and find some good examples on matching all urls like this:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file
@route("/<url:re:.+>")
def hello(url):     
   return template('page_template', url=url)    

@route('/static/<filepath:path>', name='static')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='static')

run()
```

My questions are:
1) It doesn't match root. So if I type "localhost", it doesn't work.
2) Since there are static files, I have another route for static files serving. So if I type localhost/static/page, it doesn't return "hello world".

I believe I need to modify the regex (/<:re:.+>) to deal with both situations. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

@Michael

Comment: Don't know much bottle but do you need a 'url' in there? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189597/792238

Comment: (FTR, best to ask one question per post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: You can "stack" routes quite straightforwardly.  Just do this:

```
@route("/")
@route("/<url:re:.+>")
def hello(url):     
   return template('page_template', url=url)
```

That will treat root the same as your existing regex route.

---

As for overlapping routes, according to [the documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/routing.html#routing-order), dynamic routes are evaluated in the order in which they were defined.